# Debug javascript used in a Java application

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, rhino

I work on a java standalone project that use rhino to run javascript.
Those scripts are mainly objects manipulation.

Using logger in the javascript is not always enough so i would like to use something like the java debugger in eclipse.

I can't find a way to debug the javascript files in Eclipse: even if I put breakpoint in my files, the scripts execution is never suspended.

I run Eclipse Kepler and have the Javascript Development Tools plugin.

Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: You won't debug your Javascript with a Java Debugger, that's for sure.

Comment: Not sure if this helps/you're already aware, but modern browsers (read: not ie) contain ways to view and debug code in the browser. For example in firefox, right click -> Inspect element -> Debugger. There you can set break points and step through many files. I've not used rhino, so I cant say if it applies to your situation for sure.

Comment: @meskobalazs : that's why I ask for help.

Comment: @schil227: my scripts are not run in a browser. they are interpreted by rhino directly in my app.

Comment: AFAIK the best way currently is using the debugger of a browser, I am quite satisfied with Firebug. Unfortunately JS is sorely lacking when it comes to debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rhino has a visual debugger built in (`org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.Main`) which you can use to [debug embedded scripts](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/javascript-debugging-with-embedded-rhino.html).

You can also [use Eclipse to debug embedded Rhino](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/javascript-debugging-with-embedded.html) using the `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.rhino.debugger` and `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.transport` plugins in Juno (presumably this works in later versions too.)